# How to make floating ladders

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to know how I can make floating ladders in Minceraft, preferably without Single Player Commands, like the below picture in survival singleplayer. I have MCEdit if this can be done in MCEdit.

Thank you for any helpful information.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK you could place the ladders on the blocks and then MCEdit out the blocks. Of course, a block update would make them all fall down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can't be done in vanilla survival(without commands/external tool/switching version) in my knowledge. However, it is possible with `/setblock` command due to the current bug in the game which prevents block update([MC-50166](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-50166)).

First, pillar up some blocks with [block entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_entity#List_of_block_entities) (such as furnaces, dispensers, command blocks, etc.) and attach ladders on them.

[image: Step one]

Second, stand on top of the pillar and run this command repeatedly until you get to the ground: `/setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air`. Ignore the error message.

[image: Step two]
[image: Error]

Then you will have truly floating ladders right in front you! Congrats!

[image: Voila]

Comment: Of curiosity, why must they be blocks with tile entities?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not sure how/why it is happening, but it's very peculiar bug. Minecraft is Minecraft I guess.

Comment: The bug you link to was fixed in 1.12

Comment: @pppery Any kind of update suppression will do.

Comment: You should still provide a different update suppression method in the answer, if the current one was fixed.

Comment: @pppery I am just not interested in this game as well anymore, so if anyone has the time and passion to formulate this into well explained answer, thank you so much. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJhZpK-8p54 I'm sorry to leave it like this.

Answer (score 12):

You can add invisible "barriers" and put ladders on them. See [this link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Barrier) for more information about them.

It needs at least version 1.8 in order to work.

To get some barriers:

> /give @p minecraft:barrier 64

@p stands for the nearest player (which is always you, Note: not in command blocks) and 64 stands for amount.

Also it says,

> All dependent blocks can be placed on a barrier, such as trapdoors or redstone.

and

> Barriers are transparent to light.

So you can make somethink look like this all the time, not sure that solid blocks are what you want, but I hope I helped you.

Comment: This is what I thought of as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Put barrier's on the back of the ladders

To get barrier's in PE write this command,
/give @p barrier

To get barrier's in Java write this command,
/give @p minecraft:barrier

Barrier's are invisible blocks. When barrier held in hand you can see all the barrier's you put
but when it is not in your hand they are just plain invisible solid blocks